# VBA add Javascript to Adobe Field & Set Date Format?

Tags: javascript, vba, pdf

Good afternoon,
I have an excel vba being run when a button is clicked to print to PDF.  the script then opens the PDF, add's two signature boxes and two form fields (text).

My two part question is

1. how do i format the PDF form field i created to a date form field?  The VBA that creates the PDF text field is as follows.

   ````
   coords = Array(thlft + 311, thtop - 26, thrt + 242, thebot)
   Set formField = JSO.addField("sca_date", "text", 0, coords)   '0 = 1st page 
   formField.textSize = 6
   formField.textFont = "Arial"
   formField.StrokeColor = JSO.Color.transparent```
   ````

I've examined Adobe's JavaScript™ for Acrobat® API Reference.  There are references for creationdate and modified date - but not that I could find to format a text field as a date or just put in a date field.

2. Is it possible to add javascript to the signature fields?  What I mean is right now I can manually open that newly created PDF, click on properties for one of the signature boxes - click signed tab.  Then select "this script executes when field is signed".  Then I put in some js that will enter the date in the date field when signed. and email the PDF out.  What I'd rather do is when I click print to PDF - it puts that javascript into the PDF document for me?  I hope that makes sense.  I realize I can enter a date into the field with VBA but the date of when the form will be signed is not yet known.

For this one I just couldn't find anything.  Mostly the results pertain to coding javascript with VBA but not embedding JS with VBA.

Answer (score 0):

1. Based on the addField documentation,there appears to be no "date"-type form field available - any date field is just a "text"-type field like the one you already have.
2. look at the "setAction" method for adding script handlers

https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/AcrobatDC_js_api_reference.pdf

Maybe also relevant:  https://community.adobe.com/t5/acrobat/can-acrobat-auto-populate-a-date-field-upon-digital-signature-of-a-form/td-p/4524073?page=1

Comment: Thank you Tim. I was hoping that there would be another jso that would allow the formatting of the text field. it really feels like there is - I just haven't been able to find it yet. I'll take a look at the setAction